# Receiving "Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path" error in Swift Playground using Realm.IO

Tags: xcode, swift, realm

I have installed Realm.IO (0.97.0) using Cocoapods (0.39) into my project as instructed.

When I create a Swift playground (Xcode 7.2), with something like:

```
import RealmSwift

class Unit: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""
}

let unit = Unit(value: ["name": "Moya"])

do {
  try       NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.path!)
} catch {}

let realm = try! Realm()

realm.beginWrite()
realm.add(unit)
try! realm.commitWrite()

let results = realm.objects(Unit)
results.count
```

I get the error in the console:

```
2015-12-28 11:13:13.877 Realm[39396:2067298] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/gx/699y9yv15gg2zr5sqtmtpnt80000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Realm-395D9AEC-443D-446F-AF34-EB74AA840501/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Realm-395D9AEC-443D-446F-AF34-EB74AA840501. Errno:1
2015-12-28 11:13:13.878 Realm[39396:2067298] Failed to obtain sandbox extension for path=/var/folders/gx/699y9yv15gg2zr5sqtmtpnt80000gp/T/com.apple.dt.Xcode.pg/containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Realm-395D9AEC-443D-446F-AF34-EB74AA840501/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.iOS_Simulator.Realm-395D9AEC-443D-446F-AF34-EB74AA840501. Errno:1
```

The playground results themselves work as expected. However, this error is bothersome. What can I do to eliminate it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're facing might be just some internal state corruption in Xcode, it might help to restart Xcode and / or clear the caches (as seen in the error message).

Be aware though that there are some limitations with [using Realm in playgrounds](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/938).

Comment: Thanks. Cleared the caches, reinstalled Xcode. Still the same result. I'll just ignore it in the meantime, as everything after the error messages does work.